# flex regular expression in multiple match condition

Tags: expression, flex-lexer

I can to use flex regular expression to find a match on "hello world" with double quote, the flex regular expression would be ["][^"\n]*["], as the result, I could get match case as hello world string without double quote. However, what happen if the string in "hello"""world", how can I use the flex regular expression to get the result as hello"""world? thanks.

Comment: you want anything between Quotes and /n is not permitted in between quotes!!!! am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by allowing double quotes as an alternative to any single character in the string. At the moment you have a character in the string as `[^"\n]`. To expand that to allow the double quotes as an alternative you write `[^"\n]|\"\"`. A complete example flex program would look like this:

```
stringchar  ([^\"\r\n]|\"\")
ws           [ \t\r\n]+
%%
{ws}    printf("Whitespace: \"%s\"\n",yytext);
\"{stringchar}*\"   printf("String: %s\n",yytext);
[^ \t\r\n]+ printf("Not a string: \"%s\"\n",yytext);
%%
```

You should also note that **flex** has problems with matching adjoining tokens (see [How to make lex/flex recognize tokens not separated by whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026358/how-to-make-lex-flex-recognize-tokens-not-separated-by-whitespace) ) for details. This means that `"Hello"World"` gets matched as `"Not a String"` and not a `String` followed by `"Not a String"`.